# Reactjs with cordova

Tags: cordova, reactjs, hybrid-mobile-app

Can someone help me in setting up configuration to build a Mobile app using reactjs and Cordova. I tried using pasting my react js app to www in Cordova and changing some configuration. But getting white screen. Can someone help me in setting up or some steps need to be followed to get it running.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details as to what setup you are using for development and build? Ideally, there should be a command to `build`, which will generate a `bundle.js` or a `main.js` or something similar.

You can then move this file to the `www` directory in cordova and link to it from `www/index.html` to get things working.

Comment: For creating Cordova app i am using "Cordova create appname" and for reactjs app i am using "create-react-app my-app" after adding platform to the Cordova project, i am using Cordova build android and then Cordova run android.

Comment: Use `npm run build` or `yarn build` - See documentation https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build

Comment: How can I link Cordova and react. Only react web app i am able to run properly and getting it in chrome.

Comment: You are most probably running the react app from a local web server. You need to execute `npm run build` or `yarn build` - which will generate a `.js` file that you can link from the `index.html` in `www`